# Wowza vs Evostream for react native live video streaming app

Tags: video, react-native, video-streaming, wowza, evo

I'm working on developing a live video streaming mobile app like Bigo Live.
I will be using react native for building the mobile app.

I'm trying to choose a media server Evostream or wowza for this. My requirement is video streaming with 20 concurrent broadcasters with 200 viewers for each broadcaster.

My comparision points are integration with react native, API, documentation, features, performance, quality etc. We would like the solution to be vertically scalable as horizontal scaling requires more licenses.

If you have experience with any of the above media servers, please let me know your thoughts!
Thanks,
Sash

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using React Native Wowza right now streaming to/from a Amazon EC2 M4.XLarge server and while it's a tad tricky to get setup, it can be a really powerful configured correctly. There's also a React Native package available to handle the streaming: https://github.com/medlmobileenterprises/react-native-wowza-gocoder

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the reply. May i know how many concurrent streams you are able to achieve with your setup? Thanks

Comment: I'm going based off metrics I've read after hours of searching and a system with a 4 core CPU and 14 GB memory should be able to handle 50 concurrent users and 550 viewers, anything over that and you start getting into setting up edge servers that handle the load of extra users.